# Entity Framework Core ExecuteSqlInterpolated gives Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: entity-framework-core, sqlexception

I'm looping over a bunch of tables and have to delete records in each of them having a specific column name. I was able to get that list but the following line gives me the exception: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the table variable "@p0".`

```
foreach (var dsw in deleteSwModels)
{
    contextCtx.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"DELETE FROM {dsw.Name} WHERE DeleteSw = 1");
}
```

The property Name looks like `Person.Address` where Person is the schema name under which the table is placed.

The version of Entity Framework Core is 3.1.8

Comment: You must use string concatenation instead, EF created a SqlParameter for the table name

Comment: @ErikEJ How would it be rewritten in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went digging further into the exception details and in the source code at [Github ef core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/f4403c91c8eba0c55fbc08a3158269f9d0ddf033/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs).

I solved the problem by making use of the following statement instead:

```
contextCtx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"DELETE FROM {dsw.Name} WHERE DeleteSw = 1");
```

I hope it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: This does not solve the problem above. I would like to know how ExecuteSqlInterpolated works. There is no complete documentation about that.